# Transparent View color from black to other color?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I noticed that if I set views background color to transparent, the background color turns black (which I guess is default "viewport" color) after segue transition ends.

Can I change that? Of course I could just change color from transparent to purple, but maybe there is a way?

[image: iOS background color]

Comment: There is better solution for this instead of presenting as a view controller you can just add as a subview over the current controller.

Comment: What benefits I would get and how should I do that? Sory, I'm quite new to Xcode :)

Comment: If you are new than you can try the solution already answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the default background color of your `UIWindow`. Either set it from your app delegate :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

or by looking up the window of any view currently on-screen, in any view controller:

```
anyView.window.backgroundColor = ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I wanted. In my case it would be: `self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.44, green: 0.18, blue: 0.33, alpha: 1.00)`

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line:

```
self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```

Before presenting:

```
self.presentViewController(presentedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That also works, but in this case I wanted to change UIWindow color. But anyway thanks! This will be useful in one other case in this "trivia style" game.